# get wrong textbox.TextLength in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a simple email sender and what I want to do is to check if the textbox.text has 14 characters. If it's 14 - then text turns to green, if less it turns to red. I've encountered a problem when I type 14th character. It doesn't turn green. It does when I type another character which is not shown since I have MaxLength = 14, but I still need to type in that 15th character. Also when I try deleting characters, the string doesn't turn red with the first deleted char, but after a few. I've tried things like Regex and trim() thinking that there might be some special characters but it doesn't seem to work. I also recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rq7aqIKnSQ) with the issue to make it more describing.

```
private void trackBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        trackBox1.Text = RemoveSpecialCharacters(trackBox1.Text);
        trackBox1.Text = trackBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");



        errorBox.Text = trackBox1.TextLength.ToString();
        
        if (trackBox1.TextLength < 14)
        {
            trackBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        } else if (trackBox1.TextLength == 14)
        {
            trackBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green; 
        }

        trackBox1.Text.TrimEnd();

    }

   

    public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that in KeyPress your TextBox hasn't the new letter. Use KeyUp instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `trackBox1_Keypress` put your `if statement` in the `trackBox1_TextChanged` event and to count the length of the text you should use `trackbox.Text.Length` instead of `trackbox1.TextLength`

Here is a sample snippet int the `TextChanged` event that changes the color from red to green if the text length is greater than or equal to 14.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length <= 14)
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. I think I tried TextChanged but I guess I did something wrong

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if `trackBox1.TextLength` is the proper way to get the length

```
trackBox1.Text.Length //try this
//and also your event 
private void yourTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the  [Control.KeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) docs... the event fires after a key has been pressed, but *before the character actually enters the textbox*. This means that the length you're checking is one less than the length you were expecting (unless the key just pressed was backspace, which `KeyPress` also catches, in which case it is one greater than the length you were expecting).

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely read this.